# How to find the kth element of a heap

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heapsort

I need to write an algorithm that finds the k-th element of a heap using O(n +k*ln n) comparisons. It needs to sort the heap in O(n) time and find k in O(k*ln n) time. Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by `sort the heap in O(n) time`? You already have a heap, right? So, you can simply extract the maximum/minimum element (based on whether you are dealing with max/min heap) for k times. Now, as extracting a number from the heap cost `O(log n)`, so for extracting `k` times will required `O(K * log n)` in total. Please consider checking [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-th-greatest-element-in-a-max-heap/) for other efficient ways of doing this.

Comment: I think that OP means build the heap in linear time. The question is interesting - it is actually a bonus task in a book I'm reading right now(the solution is not provided). However the issue I have with the question is the lack of preparation: what have you tried so far? What is your line of thought? What is your research? Good luck :-).

Comment: Any algorithmic book or course contains a chapter about heaps with all needed information. It is worth to make own efforts to read, learn and solve the problem.